# VirtualBox VERR_VMX_NO_VMX

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vt-x

I downloaded VirtualBox, knowing that my computer has VT-X, and I just created two VMs, but when I started them, I saw this error:

[image: Click here to see it]

> <sub>VirtualBox - Error</sub>
>   Failed to start the virtual machine **Android**.
>   <sub>(Details)</sub>
>   VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).
>
> Result Code: `E_FAIL (0x80004005)`
>   Component:  ConsoleWrap
>   Interface:   IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

<sup>[Manually transcribed]</sup>

I have previously run VirtualBox on this PC flawlessly. 
Why am I getting this error now? 
How can I get VirtualBox to work?

Comment: You have installed software that isn’t compatible with Vbox. You will have to identify that software.  Information provided doesn’t allow us to do that for you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable VX-T on Dell Precision Tower 3620](https://superuser.com/questions/1288052/enable-vx-t-on-dell-precision-tower-3620)

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/601572/failed-to-open-a-session-for-the-virtual-machine-virtualbox

Comment: I have used Windows 10 and 7 to also with this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VT-x is not available, but is enabled in BIOS](https://superuser.com/questions/1153470/vt-x-is-not-available-but-is-enabled-in-bios)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Hrobky, this was helpful. At an ASUS i7 with a UEFI BIOS that does not allow to disable safe boot, on a Windows 10 without encryption, it was enough these 2 steps from your solution:

```
start->GPedit

Computer Config > Admin Templates > System > Device Guard > 
Virtualization Based Security: Disabled

admin cmd:  bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

then reboot

with change these setting at BIOS

```
Boot / Launch CSM : Enable

Boot / Launch CSM / Boot Device Control : UEFI and Legacy OPROM

Boot / Fast Boot : Disabled

Boot / OS Type : Other OS
```

Comment: Please list your CPU model and Windows version.

AFAIK Intel 8xxx are not affected anymore. There may be a great progress since Win10 1703.

Comment: CPU model Intel i7-7700 on an ASUS motherboard Prime B250M-K
Windows 10 full update at the date, sorry I do not have record of the build.

Comment: First step is working for me. Dell E5570 i7 Windows 10 2004

Answer (score 0):

#### How to enable 64bit guest support

...while **keeping following components installed**! In your case the procedure could be shorter. Just omit the steps not relevant to your setup.

- Intel 6th gen processor (Skylake). i5-6300U in my case (on 8th gen this is not an issue anymore)
- Win10 1703 (Build 15063.1631)
- UEFI Secure Boot
- Bitlocker
- TrendMicro OfficeScan antivirus (This one is actually not conflicting anymore)
- VirtualBox 6.0.4
- Hyper-V

Related errors

- "VT-x is not available" `VERR_VMX_NO_VMX`
- `VERR_SUPDRV_NO_RAW_MODE_HYPER_V_ROOT`
- seeing just 32bit OS versions in "new machine" wizard dialog

The culprit is **Virtualization Based Security (VBS)**, which uses Windows embedded virtualization hypervisor (which doesn't conflict with HyperV). This how-to does **not** describe, how to run Hyper-V and VirtualBox simultaneously, nor how to run VirtualBox on top of Hyper-V hypervisor (as stated in [Changelog 6.0.0](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Changelog-6.0)), according to the Forum, this does not work on Win10 1703.

You will be able to **switch** between HyperV and VBS working versus VirtualBox requiring a reboot.

**Remark**: If you use BitLocker, have prepared your recovery key on a paper *beforehand*! :-] It shouldn't be required though. Control Panel -> BitLocker -> Backup Recovery Key

Here's the how-to:

1. Temporarily **suspend BitLocker** (=without decryption) - this means till next reboot
2. **Reboot**, enter BIOS, (check VT-x is turned on), **disable Secure Boot**, save&quit, (BitLocker PIN entry should be omitted)
3. Login to Windows, temporarily **suspend BitLocker** again
4. Sanity check:

   - Task Manager: Performance: You should see Virtualization Enabled
   - start->msinfo: you should see "System Summary" -> "Device Guard Virtualization Based Security" running
   - VirtualBox should not list Acceleration: "Nested Paging" and "VT-x" in your guest machine's System details page.
5. start->**GPedit**

   ```
   Computer Config > Admin Templates > System > Device Guard > Virtualization Based Security: Disabled
   ```
6. admin **PowerShell**: run this official **Device Guard Readiness Tool** from Microsoft: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53337

   ```
   DG_Readiness_Tool_v3.6.ps1 -Disable
   ```

   The `-disable` option adds a boot option to disable VBS and sets bootmgr to boot into it once. This is why we turned off SecureBoot once and why in turn we needed to suspend BitLocker.
7. In **regedit** delete the following value

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\LSA\LsaCfgFlags
   ```
8. admin **cmd**:

   ```
   bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
   ```

   This disables the hypervisor and allows VirtualBox to run.
9. **Reboot**, enter BIOS, **Enable Secure Boot**, save&quit, (BitLocker PIN entry is omitted again), (Secure Boot should allow us to boot our newly created correctly signed bootloader)
10. Press F3 to **disable Credential Guard**, press F3 to **disable VBS** (You have to be quick! There is like 10s silent time-out!!)
11. **Computer reboots**, BitLocker should ask you for your PIN, Secure Boot should not be complaining about anything
12. Sanity check:

    - start->msinfo: you should see "Device Guard Virtualization Based Security" **not** running
    - VirtualBox should now list Acceleration: "Nested Paging" and "VT-x"

Now you can switch between Hyper-V (and VBS running) and VirtualBox by `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` and `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` respectively and rebooting. Don't ask me why VBS is running again despite the GPedit setting when hypervisorlaunchtype is auto - there might be some corporate settings and magic involved. Nevertheless, VirtualBox's VT-x is working :)

I definitely **don't recommend leaving VBS turned off**, as it could have something to do with Mimikatz / Kekeo protection which is quite an issue nowadays. Let's hope this wourkaround won't be necessary in a near future.

Answer (score -1):

In the setup "system" section,
"Acceleration" tab,
uncheck "Hardware Virtualization: [ ] Enable VT-x/AMD-V"
click "OK" button

Comment: This would make 64-bit guest machine unable to run.